# Compiling new Places SDK for Android Client library fails at transformClassesWithDexBuilder

Tags: android, gradle, google-places-api

I'm trying to migrate to the new [Places SDK for Android Client](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration).

I made code changes needed, however packaging the app fails on :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug task (see the stack trace below). The issue seems to be in *com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0* dependency included as a part of *com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0*
Partial dependency tree is:

```
com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0
|    ...
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava:23.5-android
...
+--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0
|    +--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0
|    |    ...
|    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
```

So the new Places SDK client library includes Guava twice and includes non Android version as well, which causes a compile error. I recognise the description looks like a bug description, but a link to the relevant bug tracker also doesn't work :(

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:405)
... 53 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:900)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:825)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:895)
... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$FutureCombiner is referenced as an interface from `com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$7`.
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue when migrating to the new Places SDK and i solved it by excluding `com.google.guava:guava-jdk5` dependency

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

If you have another dependency that relies on guava you may need to exclude the entire group and not only the `guava-jdk5` module.

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

Comment: Excluding guava all together (the second option) worked for me